# Assessing carrier Risk

Tags: genetics, pedigree

susan has been found to be a carrier of Tay Sachs. what is the risk that her maternal aunt is also a carrier if we don't know her parents status?

Comment: I believe it should be 1/2 since her mom is also 1/2. I just want to know if I am right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to know that Tay–Sachs disease is an autosomal recessive genetic disorder. Below we will assume that the mutation is at low frequency in the population.

**Probability that Susan's maternal grandparents carry the mutation**

The probability that Susan's mother carry the mutation is $\frac{1}{2}$. The probability that the mutation is present the Susan's maternal grandparents is therefore also $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Probability that Susan's aunt received the mutation if her parents where carrying it**

Now, if the mutation is present in Susan's maternal grandparents in a single copy (which is a consequence of the assumption of the mutation being at low frequency in the population), then the probability that the sister of Susan's mother received this allele is $\frac{1}{2}$ too.

**Putting these two probabilities together**

Putting these together. $\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$. The probability is $\frac{1}{4}$.